# For which value of x $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{nx}}{n!}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to know for which values of $x$ this series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{nx}}{n!}$$ converges.

This series is defined $ \forall x \in R$.

$a_n=\frac{n^{nx}}{n!}= \frac{(n^x)^{n}}{n!}= \frac{(n^x)}{n} \frac{(n^x)}{n-1} 
 \frac{(n^x)}{n-2}...\frac{(n^x)}{3}  \frac{(n^x)}{2}   \frac{(n^x)}{1}= n^{x-1} \frac{n^{x-1}}{1-\frac{1}{n}}...\frac{(n^x)}{3}  \frac{(n^x)}{2}   \frac{(n^x)}{1}
 \sim 0 \Leftrightarrow   x<1$.

Applying the ratio test:

$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)x}}{(n+1)!} \frac{n!}{(n)^{nx}}=\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)x}}{n+1} \frac{1}{(n)^{nx}}=\frac{(n+1)^{nx+x-1}}{n^{nx}} \sim \frac{(n)^{nx+x-1}}{n^{nx}}= (n)^{x-1}<1 \Leftrightarrow x-1<0   \Leftrightarrow x<1 $

Is it right?

Comment: Is the fact $(n+1)^{nx+x-1} \sim n^{nx+x+1-1}$ obvious?

Comment: I would guess that the root test combined with the Stirling formula should give the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, denoting $ f_{n}:x\mapsto\frac{n^{nx}}{n!} \cdot $

If $ x\geq 1 $, observe that $ f_{n}\left(x\right)\geq\frac{n^{n}}{n!}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{n}{k}}\geq\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{k+1}{k}}=n $, meaning $ \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{f_{n}\left(x\right)}=+\infty\neq 0 $, which means $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 1}{f_{n}\left(x\right)} $ diverges.

If $ x<1 $, using d'Alembert's ratio test, $ \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{f_{n+1}\left(x\right)}{f_{n}\left(x\right)}}=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)x}}{n^{nx}\left(n+1\right)}}=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\left(n+1\right)^{x-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}}=0<1 $, meaning $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 1}{f_{n}\left(x\right)} $ converges.

Answer (score 0):

For these I always use
$n! \sim (n/e)^n$.

So
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{nx}}{n!}
\sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{nx}}{(n/e)^n}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (en^x/n)^n
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (en^{x-1})^n
$

so we want
$en^{x-1} < 1
$
or,
taking logs,
$1+(x-1)\ln(n) < 0$
or
$(x-1)\ln(n) < -1
$.

This is false if
$x \ge 1$,
and is true
if $x < 1$.

To check,
write $x = 1-c$.
the terms are

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{n^{nx}}{n!}
&\sim \frac{n^{n(1-c)}}{(n/e)^n}
&= \frac{n^{n(1-c)}e^n}{n^n}
&= n^{-cn}e^n
&= (n^{-c}e)^n
\end{array}
$

which goes to zero
only if $c > 0$.

Comment: Why aren't you considering the factor $\sqrt {2 * \pi *n}$?

Comment: in the stirling's approximation $n! \sim \frac {1}{\sqrt {2* \pi* n}* \frac {n^n}{e^n}}$

Comment: That only affects convergence at the boundaries, not the interior.